# Convert UK Postcode to Lat / Lng in Objective-C iOS iPhone etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am wondering how I can convert a **UK Postcode** to Lat / Lng within my app so that I can pass this onto a `URL`.

I am parsing my data as JSON to be used later in a map
eg: `http://www.thebigfishexperience.org.uk/sources/ajax/venue-json.php?lat=52.5612743&lng=-0.2732938&radius=10`

The `lat` and `lng` parameters would be generated by the app and would push to something like the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have postcode, you need to do reverse geocoding but that can be done using MapKit. Check this [iPhone Development – Reverse Geocoding](http://evilrockhopper.com/2010/01/iphone-development-reverse-geocoding/)

If you do not want to use MapKit, you can request to url http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=UKPOSTCODE&output=xml, and parse xml, you will get latitude longitude.

Answer (score 4):

To convert a UK postcode to a Latitude and Longitude, use [Google's Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=POSTCODE&sensor=false
```

You will receive a JSON response which you can easily parse to populate your hidden fields.

Comment: Keyless access to Google Map API is now deprecated. You will need to sign up with google.